# Есть ли возможность обрабатывать ошибки в package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js

У меня в файле package.json

есть простой скрипт, что бы делать push изменений

```
  "scripts": {
    "gitHub": "git status && git add -A && git commit -am 'update' && git push"
  },
```

Но если изменений нет, у меня появляется ошибка в консоли.

Есть ли возможность сделать какой нибудь exception ?

Дополнение:
Вывод в консоль, если нет изменений в репозитории

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Цель-то какая? Что бы не было ошибки в консоли?

Comment: Да. Либо прерывать выполнение, либо если это возможно отловить ошибку и какое то другое действие назначить. Я не понимаю, что в данном случае вообще можно сделать. В дополнении прикрепил принтскрин с выводом консоли.